# Como resolver "Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Message"?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Estava estudando JSF e encontrei este site onde ensina a criar um chat básico usando JSF, primefaces e ajax: 
https://jetcracker.wordpress.com/2012/03/04/jsf-how-to-create-a-chat-with-ajax/

Tenho a classe MessageManager

```
public class MessageManager implements MessageManagerLocal {

    private final List messages =
            Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList());;

    @Override
    public void sendMessage(Message msg) {
        messages.add(msg);
        msg.setDateSent(new Date());
    }

    @Override
    public Message getFirstAfter(Date after) {
        if(messages.isEmpty())
            return null;
        if(after == null)
            return messages.get(0);
        for(Message m : messages) {
            if(m.getDateSent().after(after))
                return m;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Porém ele ocorre um erro nesta linha `return messages.get(0);` e nesta `for(Message m : messages) {`.

O primeiro erro fala para fazer um *cast*, então fiz e o erro sumiu, mas o segundo erro (`for(Message m : messages) {`) ele aponta a seguinte mensagem:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Message

Como posso resolver este erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema neste caso é que você não especifica qual o tipo de objeto que existe na `LinkedList` em

```
private final List messages = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList());
```

então a JVM não tem como garantir que esse `Object` é uma instância de um `Message`. Para resolver isso, você só precisa mudar a declaração para

```
private final LinkedList<Message> messages = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<Message>());
```

Outra alternativa é de fato rodar o loop com um `Object`, mas dar cast para `Message` logo em seguida:

```
for(Object o : messages) {
    Message m = (Message) o;
    if(m.getDateSent().after(after))
        return m;
}
```

Comment: muito obrigado!